# is there an optimized way to implement following/unfollowing a fan page (nodejs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, react-native

I want to implement a route in nodejs, where a user can follow or unfollow an artist. i have a simple way to achieve this, but then i'm thinking of the future.

When a fan now has lots of followers, the way i've written it, wouldn't be optimized at all. so i need a more optimized version of what i have already please.

```
export const followArtist = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // Add your registration logic here
  console.log("Following artist ...");
  try {
    const { artistId, userId, action } = req.body;

    const artist: any = await ArtistModel.findById(castToObjectId(artistId));
    const user: any = await User.findById(castToObjectId(userId));

    if (!artist || !user)
      return res
        .status(404)
        .send("Sorry, you weren't able to follow this artist");

    console.log(artist);

    artist.fans += 1;
    artist.fans_list?.push(userId);

    user.following.push(artistId);

    await artist.save();
    await user.save();

    return res.status(200).send("successfully followed");
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send("An error occured retrieving the artists.");
  }
};
```

What i'd like to achieve with this route ?
req.body = {
"artistId": "65d4c5ee1d0c23702df691f2",
"action": "follow",
"userId": "65d4a69aa1c8183bd36caa04"
}

1. if action === "follow"
   then, I want to add the userId to the fan_list array field of the artist and also add the artist's id to the following array of the user and then increment the fans field by 1

2 if action === "unfollow"
then, I want to search for the userId in the fan_list array of the artist, remove it there and also remove it from the user's following array. and then decrement the fans field by 1

the only problem is, if the fan has 20,000 followers, which means, node will have to loop through these 20k fans to find the user's Id to perform the action and then loop through the user's list too.

So please i need an optimized way to do this. thanks